# htaccess redirect to file in other directory

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

How can I load requested file from another directory (using `.htaccess`) if that file is not found at the requested URL?

For example:

**Request:**: `mysite.com/samples/image_requested.jpg` (does not exist)

**Output:** `mysite.com/samples/missing/image_requested.jpg` (without showing the exact url in the browser)

I tried this but it gives me a `500 Internal Error`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/samples/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/samples/missing/
RewriteRule ^samples/(.+)$ /samples/missing/$1
```

Comment: I don't know how to create the condition or I didn't get your idea...but you can redirect it: RewriteRule ^/samples/missing/image_requested.jpg$ /samples/image_requested.jpg - You could try to replace "(.+)$" for this "([^.]+)$"

Comment: Thanks for reply."([^.]+)$" wont fire. It gives me 404 error

Comment: Consider to post your question on this forum - http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^/samples/$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^\/samples/missing/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /samples/missing/$1

Comment: Unfortunately this nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example for jpg, png and gif files. It will display always the requested URL (*/samples/file.jpg*), not the real one (*/samples/missing/file.jpg*):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule samples/(.*\.(jpg|png|gif)) samples/missing/$1 [L]
```